# Tikz matrix with header row

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a tikz matrix where the first row is a header row with nodes that are centered and all other rows after that have the text left aligned

```
   H1      H2      H3
 adfsf   34993   ddddd
 234     220     ,,,,,,
 239494  349     ...
```

H1 is centered horizontally in it's column. Same for H2 and H3. All the other text is centered left in their columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you assign a value for `text width` for the column nodes, then you can use the `align` key (I only used `draw` to have a visual reference):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
every node/.style={draw},
column 1/.style={text width=60pt,align=left},
column 2/.style={text width=80pt,align=left},
column 3/.style={text width=125pt,align=left},
row 1/.style={align=center},
]
{
Header 1 & Header2 & Header 3 \\
text text text & text text text & text text text text text\\
text text & text text text text & text text text text text text\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]